# how to use plugin in cordova/ionic framework

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic-framework

i wanna to import a sample plugin to test in cordova/ionic,i try this

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

now in my index.html i use this codes

```
var model = device.model;
document.write(device.model);
```

then

```
cd myionicApp
cordova emulate
```

but it doesn't work,can anyone help me?
also installed cordova CLI and Cordova Plugman and Ionic Framework

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
var model = device.model;
document.write(device.model);
```

in

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", success, error);
function success(){
    var model = device.model;
    document.write(device.model);
};
function error(){

};
```

In your case it did not worked because plugins are not called until device is ready. So we need to add device ready listener. Then only any of plugins will be called.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');
        element.innerHTML = 'Device Model: '    + device.model    + '<br />' +
                            'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova  + '<br />' +
                            'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' +
                            'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' +
                            'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
    }

    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
   </body>
   </html>
```